# Vue - resetting form but still getting red invalidated box

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a "Add Task" form with required fields (name, description, etc.). Here's a relevant snippet of it:

```
<v-form ref="form">
    <v-row class="mx-5">
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
            <v-autocomplete clearable outlined v-model="task.full_name" :items="students" :item-text="'name'" :item-value="'name'" :name="'name'" label="Full name*" :rules="required" return-object @change="setPhoneNumber"></v-autocomplete>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
            <v-autocomplete clearable outlined @change="checkLocation" v-model="pickedLocation" :items="locations" label="Location*" :rules="required"></v-autocomplete>
        </v-col>
```

Once the task is added successfully, in a `getter` function I update several things and reset the form:

```
this.color = 'success'
this.added = true
this.isPressed = false
this.dialog = false
this.$refs.form.reset()
this.fetchTasks()
```

All the input boxes are indeed reset - they are empty and there are no validation errors. All but one. The "Full name" box (the first in the snippet above) is empty, but the box is red, indicating a validation error. I have no idea why the validation on this specific input box is raised, even though I reset the form. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for this issue?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I tried but as the app is a bit complicated with several different parts I'm having trouble whittling it down to a working example.